# How to diagnose potential JFFS2 flash problems?

Tags: filesystems, flash-memory

I have a large fleet of embedded ARM systems using the JFFS2 filesystem.  Are there any particular commands or log file entries I can query to gauge whether they are having any corruption or other problems?

Answer (score 0):

On Debian and derivatives you can periodically check the integrity of files installed by the package manager, by using the "-V" (--verify) option to dpkg.

Alternatively, for older versions of Debian there is the "debsums" package.

For other scenarios than the above, and for configureable data, a tool like "tripwire" might suit your needs.